# DataTemplate bind to Nested Class Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class:

```
public MainClass
{
    ...
    object myResources; //Which contains a SubClass's object
}
```

And this is the sub class:

```
public SubClass
{
    string imgLoc;
}
```

Now I need to bind an image's source to the location:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainClass}">
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding myResources.imgLoc}" />
        </Image.Source>               
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

Which obviously won't work, but I have no idea how to do this. Can someone shine some light for me? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried that? If you make all the things you're trying to access *public properties*, it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes I have tried that. They are all public properties, but threw an XamlParseException during runtime. I suspect is it because it isn't casting object myResources to SubClass myResources during runtime?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your objects as:

```
public MainClass
{
    public object myResources {get; set;}
}
```

and...

```
public SubClass
{
    public string imgLoc {get; set;}
}
```

... then the binding you're proposing will work just fine. This works because the WPF framework will reflect into the sub-object, and check if it has an `imgLoc` public property.